# Implode function suddenly stopped working

Tags: php, postgresql

This was working perfectly... I made some adjustments to the where clause of the select statement on the form from which the post is sourced and now it is no longer working. Any idea why I am suddenly getting an implode error?

> Warning: implode() [function.implode]: Invalid arguments passed on line 9

```
  <?php
// show error messages
ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL);
ini_set("display_errors", 1);

$datea= $_POST["userDatea"];
$media= $_POST["userMedia"];
$datez= $_POST["userDatez"];
$media_names = "'".implode( "%','", $media)."%'";


//var_dump($media_names);

if( !empty($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']) && (strcasecmp($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'], 'post')===0)  ) {
// Create connection
$conn = pg_connect("dbconnection info");

// Check connection
if (!$conn) {
echo "Did not connect.\n";
exit;
}
$result = pg_query($conn,
"SELECT
date (b.starttime),
Count(b.starttime) as Plays,
Count(distinct(b.playerid)) as Stores

FROM
public.billing b,
public.medias m,
public.players p

WHERE
b.mediaitemid = m.id and
p.id = b.playerid and
m.name LIKE any (array[$media_names]) and
b.starttime >= date('$datea') and 
b.starttime < date('$datez')+1 and
m.startdate >  '2015-01-01'

GROUP BY
date (b.starttime)

ORDER BY
date (b.starttime);");

if (!$result) {
  echo "Query failed.\n";

  exit;
}

 $num_fields = pg_num_fields($result);
    $headers = array();

    for ($i = 0; $i < $num_fields; $i++) 
    {
        $headers[] = pg_field_name($result , $i);
    }

    $fp = fopen('php://output', 'w');
    if ($fp && $result)
    {
            header('Content-Type: text/csv');
            header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="customreport.csv"');
            header('Pragma: no-cache');
            header('Expires: 0');
            fputcsv($fp, $headers);

            while ($row = pg_fetch_row($result)) 
            {
                 fputcsv($fp, array_values($row));
            }
            die;

}
        exit('It works');
    }
?>
```

Here is the source of the post:

```
<select multiple name="userMedia" class="form-control" id="userMedia[]" style="height:350px;">
 <?php

$conn = pg_connect("db connection");

if (!$conn) {
echo "Did not connect.\n";
exit;
}
$sql = "SELECT 
        m.name
        FROM 
        public.medias m
        where 
        date(m.enddate) >= date(now()) - interval '183 days' and
        date(m.startdate) > '2015-01-01' and
        m.enddate != ''

        UNION ALL

        SELECT 
        m.name
        FROM 
        public.medias m
        where 
        m.enddate = '' and
        date(m.startdate) > '2015-01-01';";
$rs = pg_query($conn, $sql);


if (pg_num_rows($rs) > 0) {
// output data of each row
while($row = pg_fetch_assoc($rs)) {
$menu .= "<option value=".$row['name'].">" . $row['name']. "</option>";
}
}

echo $menu;

pg_close($conn); 

?> 
</select></p>
```

Comment: You forgot to tell us what was the error you were facing...

Comment: Quick on the downvote draw... Thank you for pointing that out. It is now added.

Comment: Which is the line number 9? Sorry, downvote removed.

Comment: $media_names = "'".implode( "%','", $media)."%'";

Comment: what is this `LIKE any (array[$media_names]) and` supposed to do?

Comment: @KevMoe What's in `var_dump($media)`? And yeah, with Jeff...

Comment: $media_names is an array of selected items from a list imploded to reflect this...
'COMM_7030%','COMM_7029%',etc...

Comment: `Any idea why I am suddenly getting an implode error?`=>it's because you adjusted your where clause but forget to change implode() code accordingly. shhow us the output of  `var_dump($media);`

Comment: Ok, I am running the file now. It may take a few. All I did was limit the results with a date restriction. I did not change how the file names would be formatted.

Comment: I did not get any return from var_dump($media)... I do get the results of the query though...

Comment: Got the dump... "COMM_7030"... Though it should be two files. COMM_7030 and COMM_7029

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the first argument you pass to [`implode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) is a string (the "glue"), it expects the second argument to be an [`array`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php).

When `$media` (initialized using `$_POST["userMedia"]`) is not an array, `implode()` triggers the warning and returns `NULL` instead of the string you expect.

Comment: Ok, why would userMedia suddenly no longer be an array?

Comment: Because the form processed by this script was modified...? Maybe the field doesn't even exist in the form. Or (less likely) the form is now submitted using `GET` and because of that `$_POST[]` is empty.

Comment: The form was not modified, just the select statement that populates it.

Comment: `print_r($_POST)` will tell you what's wrong with `$userMedia`

Comment: Thank you... This is the response...

Array ( [userMedia] => COMM_7030 [userDatea] => 2017-07-03 [userDatez] => 2017-07-07 )

Comment: I selected two files not sure why it is only taking one of them.

Comment: It should be `<input name="userMedia[]">` (notice the square brackets) in order to send multiple values from the form and to be decoded as array in `$_POST['userMedia']`.